# MarkLogic OPTIC Query not returning results when Protected Paths are configured

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

i loaded the employee data with sample structure as below

```
<employee>
  <id>value</id>
  <first-name>first</first-name>
  <last-name>last</last-name>
   <address></address>
</employee>
```

created a template to get id, first-name and last-name which works as expected.

the simple optics query to get results using op:from-view("customer", "employee") => op:result() is working as expected.

But when i configured protected path on first-name and last-name the same query is not returning any results.

do i need to give any permissions in template even though i am running query as admin user in QC?

Comment: Just to add, any other documents with different template with out protected paths is working as expected. only when i enable protected path on any one of the fields its not returning any results.

Answer (score 2):

You can only search on, and pull values from indexes containing protected values with users that have a role that is part of the query roleset associated with the protected path.

Admin role does bypass security in most areas of MarkLogic, but protected paths is one of the few exceptions. An admin user can pull up the full document, including protected data, but not search on it, unless you add a role listed in the query roleset.

So, give your admin user the appropriate role to access protected data, and it will work.

HTH!

Comment: i tried running the optics query as the user having access to protected paths and also tried giving admin all the additional roles with which field is protected. but still empty response only.

the user/role access to protected path is able to search document similar to admin. But the optic query is not returning any results for both.

tde:extract-data-extract is working with out any issues in QC

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution after me contacting the MarkLogic support.

once i give the document level permission only the user i gave protected path access/query rolesets. every thing works as expected for that user.

if i need to get it working for admin. i need to do the same for admin too so that i can get the data i need (as the triples are created based on the template in security db).

good learning i had now :)